# Receiving an excel file from an HTTP POST request and embedding it into a Weebly website

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, weebly

I have a sensor recording data every minute and updating an excel/csv file with the results, done in python. I then use requests.post to create an HTTP request sending the file to a Weebly website. I believe I need to use JavaScript on the website to receive the excel file and embed it into the website. I have been stuck on this part for a few days since I have never used JavaScript before. The question is: How can I create a JavaScript code to receive the file and embed it into the Weebly website?

From the research I have done thus far it appears that I need to use an XMLHttpRequest GET to request the data being sent from python, I am a little confused though because it requires a url. Through more research it looks like I may need to set up a server to send it to and request it from although I am not sure if that is necessary or how to do it.

```
import requests
with open('/home/pi/Images_for_Python/2/100001.csv','rb') as f:
    r = requests.post("http://www.greeniethegenie123.weebly.com", files={'/home/pi/Images_for_Python/2/100001.csv':f})
print(r.text)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest trying something like XMLHttpRequest Get or jQuery $.get() on your original question. If you are using a raspberry pi, you can use that to 'serve' up the data. If it is on your home network, you can use your home IP Address as the URL if you do not have the system in place to point/route a domain. The address would be http:// Your IP Address/path/to/file.csv. If you have SSL (https://) on your Weebly site but not your raspberry pi IP Address/Domain you'll likely run into issues with security. (A different platform/host for either or/or both would help).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having the same problem I have found an alternative solution through Amazon Web Services (AWS). They have a setup that works quite well for this called AWS IoT Analytics. It made this a trivial problem due to its python module that connects directly to the data server!